# Get wordpress multisite site id

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a multisite in which people pay to upgrade to adfree. I have a list of blog id's that are from upgraded sites. I am trying to place code in the page that gets the current blog id but it doesnt seem to work. i am always getting site id 1 returned. Any ideas?

```
<?php

$current_site = get_current_site();
$id = $current_site->id;
echo $id;
$os = array(267,156, 98,654);

if (in_array($id, $os)) {
echo "dont display ads";
}

?>
```

thanks

EDIT. Working Code

```
 <?php

 global $blog_id;
 $os = array(286,156, 98,654);
 if (in_array($blog_id, $os)) {
 echo "dont display ads";
 }


?>
```

Comment: Have you googled `Get wordpress multisite site id`? It gets me [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-current-site-blog-id) which seems to answer the question fully.

Comment: i tried that before and i couldent get it to work, another try and it works fine now. Thanks for the jolt!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (in_array($id, $os)) {
```

You are missing `$` sign from in front of id

also ensure that $current_site->id does return a number (like `98` for example, not `'98,654'` string (or float) )